# How to customise columns in Add Products popup

Tags: lightning, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, product

**Question**

How do I customise the columns that appear in the `Add Products` popup which appears if you click the `Add Products` button on the Products related list on the `Opportunities` record page?

**What I've tried**

Instructions I found online tell me to do this:

> You can select fields in `Mini Page Layout` to appear on that popup.
>
> Follow given steps :
>
> 1. Go to the `Opportunity Product` object
> 2. Edit the page layout
> 3. In the header there is a `Mini Page Layout` link
> 4. Click on that link and select fields which you want for popup to display
> 5. Save the layout

But, the columns which are configured in the `Mini Page Layout` are not the same as the columns which are appearing in the `Add Products` popup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Follow given steps :

1. Go to the `Price Book Entry` object
2. Select `Search Layouts`
3. Edit `Search Results`
4. Change the fields
5. Press `Save`

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the same issue and you need to add it to the "Multi-line" view. For instance we wanted to include a lookup to a partner account when adding the product and we then added "Partner" lookup field to the "Multi-Line" view (it's next to the mini console layout.)

Hope this helps.